# Title bar doesn't show on emulator but shows in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, graphical-layout-editor

I don't want an activity in my app to show the title bar. So I added the following line to that activity in the manifest: `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"`. Now that activity does not show the title bar, but the `graphical layout editor` section in eclipse shows it. I need to get rid of the title bar in eclipse too. How do I remove it from eclipse's `graphical layout editor`?

Comment: in Eclipse, choose Theme.Black.NoTitleBar (in the toolbar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your version of Eclipse, there should be a drop-down menu below at the top of tht view.  The Themes can be selected from there.  It let's you do it this way so that you can see what your app will look like with different themes.

Answer (score 1):

There is a dropdown above the graphical layout editor. This screenshot might help you -

[image]